# How do a generate a JavaScript function scoped variable with Blockly?

Tags: blockly

I have a function block in my Blockly workspace, but I can't seem to find a way to add a variable that is scoped to a function. Adding a variable to the workspace generates a variable defined at the top of my generated code.

Is there a way with the pre-built blocks to create a variable within a function block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, not really; all of the variables in Blockly are global. One thing you can do is have the function block in some way know which variables it's using and then redefine it with 'let' inside the function such that it won't be modified outside of the function, but variable selectors will still be able to select the variable regardless of location.

Comment: OK, thanks for that answer. Do you know if it is even possible with a custom block? I haven't created any custom blocks yet, but perhaps if I create my own function block and my own variable block I can do this. What do you think?

Comment: With a custom block alone? No. With a custom variable selector field? Yes, but it would be *very* extensive to implement.

Comment: OK, got it. Thanks!